# Can't get AzCopy to list files in a container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm trying to use azcopy to list files in a blob container. I can only get it to tell me how many files exist but not actually return the names of the files. the command i'm using is:

```
azcopy /source:$sharedimagesource /dest:$dest /sourcekey:$srckey /S /V /L
```

The output is:

```
Listed: 2 file(s)
[2016/05/03 12:22:09] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files listed: 2
Elapsed time:       00.00:00:00
```

Any way to get the names of the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the blob names are not listed in the command line. But instead, you can specify an output file and then the copied blobs will be listed in that file. Just modifed your command as below:

```
azcopy /source:$sharedimagesource /dest:$dest /sourcekey:$srckey /S /L /V:C:\test\output.txt
```

Just specify the output path after /V parameter. I just tested and it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Would love to keep everything in memory rather than writing to files and then reading from them. I guess if this is the only way, it's the only way. I will mark this as correct because I specifically asked about AzCopy, although, I think I will go with the solution below.

Comment: @Progger thanks for marking this as answer. My answer is basically following what you are doing, there are also several other solution which can do the same thing, powershell, rest api, .NET SDK. You can choose whatever you want that suits you best.

Comment: This option (/L) is not provided in the Linux version of the .NET azcopy.  However, there is an AzCopy (v10 preview) written in go with a completely new command-line interface.  This includes a list sub-command.  See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy.

Comment: any idea how to specify the listing operation (/L) on linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell to do this:

```
$SourceStorageAccount = "yourstorageaccount"
$SourceStorageKey = "yourKey"
$SourceStorageContainer = 'yourcontainerName'
$SourceStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey

$Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -Container $SourceStorageContainer

foreach ($Blob in $Blobs)
{
   Write-Output "$Blob.Name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Azcopy now has a list option

`azcopy.exe list 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container<SAStoken>'`

Answer (score 0):

version 10
azcopy.exe list   --machine-readable  --mega-units --running-tally >>C:\TEMP\azycopyLogs\outFile_Blob_List.txt